What is 'T' rating on a glass fuse?
I have a 12VDC cuircuit board with a blown glass fuse (careless wrong polarity). The bands are brown, blue, red plus a wide blue band.  Looking at the chart it says the time/current rating is T.  Is this a quickblow fuse?


Glass fuses have color band markings? Can you post a picture?

see also: EE@SE posts containing T, fuse, blow

T is for slow blow, F for fast, FF for very fast.

(I "knew" explications different from Timed & Fast.)

I thought 'FF' was just a gag of yours, for "?*%£in' fast", but a search shows it's a real one :-) Upvoted.

I really wonder where the letters have their origin... German electricians know them as "Träge" and "Flink".


T = Time-lag.
F = Fast.

See more here: What fuse can I use to replace this old glass tube fuse?

If you don't have the datasheet: T or "Time-Delay" is generally used for slow fuses.
If you have the part type, it is better to check the datasheet.
